# FIrebase-OTP sent successfully but not verifying code in react native android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set up OTP verification in react native application using Firebase.
I followed all steps given in firebase docs phone auth.
As per code otp sent successfully but not verified.
If I use another device phone number then code is verified but if I use same phone number where application is installed(application and sim card of that phone number both are in same device) then it gives response as INVALID CODE

```
async function confirmCode() {
    try {
        let confirmation = await props.route.params.confirmation;
        await confirmation.confirm(verifyCode);
        alert("Successfully Verified!!")
        props.navigation.navigate('home')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Invalid code.');
    }
}

return (
    <View style={styles.body}>

        <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder="Verification Number" keyboardType="phone-pad"
            onChangeText={(text) => { setVerifyCode(text) }} />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { confirmCode() }} style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 19, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Verify Code</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you try with the same device and same number then you would not able to confirm the code by manually entering the OTP code.

here we have to use the onAuthStateChanged event to verify the user.

When using the device with the same number for auth then must add the event listener and handle the user auth in this listener to work auth properly.

ex:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth().onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
        if (user && user.uid) {
            await dispatch(userActions.setUpUserData(currentUser.payload));
            Toast(currentUser.message);
            mounted.current && setIsLoading(false);
            mounted.current && setShowPhoneAuth(false);
        }
    });

    return () => {
        unsubscribe();
    };
}, [currentUser]);
```

For more details check out the official docs.
1 - https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth
2 - https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage#listening-to-authentication-state

Comment: @ChaitraliSapre Glad to help you.